# How to install ia32-lib on 64 Bit System?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new on Ubuntu and setting android environment.I googled too much for this problem but nothing is helping !! when I open eclipse and test android sample project I get a error saying "R cannot be resolved"

```
Error executing aapt. Please check aapt is present at /home/rahul/android-sdks/platform-tools/aapt
Hint: On 64-bit systems, make sure the 32-bit libraries are installed: sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

on trying `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Comment: Thank you for this. If you have time to explain why this works (the top line) it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and type this

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Comment: getting rahul@ubuntu:/$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/lock
rahul@ubuntu:/$ rahul
rahul: command not found
rahul@ubuntu:/$

Comment: Now the lock file is removed. Can you try executing the command `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`

Comment: rahul@ubuntu:/$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
Reading package lists..Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information..Done
Some packages could not be installed.This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ia32-libs:Depends:ia32-libs-multiarch but it is not installable
E:Unable to correct problems,you have held broken packages

Comment: i am fighting with this problem from 2 days..installed too many packages.. re-installed ubuntu, java, eclipse and android ! but nothing is working

Comment: Ok this is different issue now . you can  solve it by typing 
sudo apt-get install -f

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  lib32asound2 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6 lib32tinfo5
  lib32z1 libc6-i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: @itsme.raahul what is the current state now? Can you use Eclipse to develop android apps?

Comment: Failed to get the adb version: Cannot run program "/home/rahul/android-sdks/platform-tools/adb": error=13, Permission denied from '/home/rahul/android-sdks/platform-tools/adb' - exists=true

Answer (score 0):

Close synaptic or any other installation program.