# How to run Android Applications in Eclipse?

Tags: 12.04, dell, android

my system is Dell Inspiron 15R (N5010) and i am having trouble becuase of 64 bit system.
on running Android Application i am getting error:

> **Error executing aapt. Please check aapt is present at /home/rahul/android-sdks/platform-tools/aapt**

before this error i was getting adb not found error.
i tried to install

> **ia32-libs**

but can't.
i also put my question here ([How to install ia32-lib on 64 Bit System?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204694/how-to-install-ia32-lib-on-64-bit-system)) but nothing helped. please help !!

Comment: is aapt present in the location it's asking you to put it?

Comment: it is present in platform-tools folder !

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a permissions problem!
just cd into your sdk folder

```
cd /home/rahul/android-sdks/android-sdk-linux
```

now  change the permissions of the required folders

```
sudo chown -R YOUR_USERNAME:YOUR_USERNAME platform-tools/  tools/ platforms/  platform-tools/adb
```

now try running your android virtual machine!

Comment: now getting error on console
'Failed to get the adb version: Cannot run program "/home/rahul/android-sdks/platform-tools/adb": error=2, No such file or directory from '/home/rahul/android-sdks/platform-tools/adb' - exists=true'
and R.java is not building

Comment: ok do one more thing sudo chown -R YOUR_USERNAME:YOUR_USERNAME platform-tools/adb

Comment: still
>Error executing aapt. Please check aapt is present at /home/rahul/android-sdks/platform-tools/aapt
>Hint: On 64-bit systems, make sure the 32-bit libraries are installed: sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
>R cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: try `chmod +x path/to/aapt`