# will 32 bit Ubuntu will work fine on 64 bit machine?

Tags: 12.04, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [amd64, i386 (32bit / 64bit) - Which version to choose?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32402/amd64-i386-32bit-64bit-which-version-to-choose)

i am getting some problems in 64 bit Ubuntu..i want to install `ia32-libs` for Android SDK but it is not installing, i tried too hard.

so i want to know that will 32-bit Ubuntu will work as good as 64-bit Ubuntu ? i have Dell Inspiron 15R (N5010).

so how can i install Ubuntu 32-bit and *can i install it direct from Windows using* **wubi** ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can install Ubuntu 32bit on a 64bit system, and contrary to popular belief, it will be able to use all of your memory (not just 4GB). Just install it using the Linux PAE kernel (installed by default) and everything will run exactly the same. PAE stands for Physical Address Extension, and it is the technology that allows the software to access over 4GB of RAM.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension

Answer (score 3):

Yes it will work but your system won't be in full use. So you may find that it won't be able to use as much RAM as your laptop has and the processor ability. Basically it won't perform as well as 64bit would.

I think more the question is here is how to install the `ia32-libs`? What errors are you getting?

Comment: exactly my first question was :
[1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/204694/how-to-install-ia32-lib-on-64-bit-system

Comment: Many programs will use more RAM when running as 64 bit, so depending on circumstance, you might find performance is actually worse on 64 bit.