# apt-get update not working + ubuntu 32-bit Vs 64-bit

Tags: apt, 32-bit, software-sources, libraries, android-studio

I am a newbie to linux platform.Please don't mark this question as duplicate before reading it completely.!

My system is running on `intel i5` processor and the OS I recently installed is `64-bit Ubuntu 13.10`. I had to install a set of libraries for my android developer tool (`ADT`) to function correctly. All started with the linuxizing of my system and development environment!

This is one of the [links](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204694/how-to-install-ia32-lib-on-64-bit-system) I sued for this purpose.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

I also used the [tips to speed up Ubuntu 13.10](http://itsfoss.com/speed-up-ubuntu-1310/)

But when ever I do a  `sudo apt-get update`, it is showing the following warning messages repeatedly many times.

```
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1)/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs    
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1)/dists/saucy/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs    
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1)/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs    
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1)/dists/saucy/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs    
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1)/dists/saucy/main/binary-i586/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs    
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1)/dists/saucy/restricted/binary-i586/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs    
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1)/dists/saucy/main/binary-i686/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs    
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1)/dists/saucy/restricted/binary-i686/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs    
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i586/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)    
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'partner/binary-i586/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)    
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i586/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)    
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/appgrid/stable/ubuntu/dists/saucy/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i586/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)    
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/apt-fast/stable/ubuntu/dists/saucy/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i586/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)    
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu/dists/saucy/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i586/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)    
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/unstable/ubuntu/dists/saucy/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i586/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)    
W: Failed to fetch ftp://ftp.iitb.ac.in/distributions/ubuntu/archives/dists/saucy/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i586/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)    
W: Failed to fetch ftp://ftp.iitb.ac.in/distributions/ubuntu/archives/dists/saucy-updates/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i586/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)    
W: Failed to fetch ftp://ftp.iitb.ac.in/distributions/ubuntu/archives/dists/saucy-security/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i586/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)    
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried solving the issues using various answers within this forum which is asking to edit the `sources.list` file. But I dont have those content ( `binary-i686 or binary-i586` ) in my sources.list file.

Can anybody help me to solve this issue!? Please don't forget to answer with the commands as I know very little about the `linux terminal commands`!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `sources.list` file,

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Remove the  lines that was stated by you on above.Then save the file.

For the  PPA's which causes error,then you have to delete that PPA file also from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory.

After that update the repositories by running,

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But I could not find those lines in my sources.list

Comment: it was started with `deb` or `deb-src`.post the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` command to pastebin.com and then provide the link here.

Comment: Then there are many. 16 of then actually. Shall I remove all lines starting with `deb` and `deb-src`?

Comment: Run this command `cp /etc/apt/sources.list ~/Desktop/source.list` before deleting the whole lines started with `deb` and `deb-src`.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/mVHeHE7v This is the link.

Comment: look for the lines you stated above and delete it from `sources.list` file.For PPA's you have to delete the corresponding PPA file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory.

Comment: When I tried running this command `cp /etc/apt/sources.list ~/Desktop/source.list` I got this line added to the last of the  output in the link provided above, `cat: /root/Desktop/source.list: No such file or directory`

Comment: please exit out of the root by running `exit` command.Then it will be like `avinash@avinash-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500:~$`

Comment: Deleted. Should I remove all of the file from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory?

Comment: exited out from the root! :)

Comment: no the PPA file which causes the error.Like remove appgrid PPA file from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.The PPA file was usually like `appgrid-ubuntu.list`

Comment: There are two files. `appgrid-saucy.list` and `appgrid-saucy.list.save`

Comment: yes delete only the file ending with `.list`.Delete only `app-grid-saucy.list` file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12992/discussion-between-droidbee-and-avinash-raj)